# ansible --ask-become-pass hangs, seeming waiting for the password

Tags: ansible

I have been getting to know ansible, and have successfully run several plays over the last couple of days, including those using `--ask-become-pass`.

Suddenly, if I use `--ask-become-pass`, I get the usual prompt for the BECOME password, but it is as though the return key is broken, and all I can do it `ctrl-c` out.

Running without `--ask-become-pass` works fine (apart from the lack of permissions).

Running with an additional `-vvv` gives me some version info before the prompt, but no hints on the reason for the problem.

```
ansible-playbook [core 2.14.3]
...
```

Running with `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1` gives me an additional line of logging:

```
18665 1681123351.90242: starting run
```

Any hints on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my terminal had got into a strange state. Typing `reset` was enough to solve the problem.

Comment: I strangely had the same issue today, and your fix worked like a charm